# Missing Azure cmdlets from PowerShell v5

Tags: powershell, azure

Alrighty so I am trying to control my first Azure instance with Powershell.
I am on windows 10, I run $PSVersionTable

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.693
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.693
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I am trying to follow this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125356.aspx

So I type "Install-Module AzureRM" That works

Then I type "Install-AzureRM"

I get:

```
Install-AzureRM : The term 'Install-AzureRM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-AzureRM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-AzureRM:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I can use "Login-AzureRmAccount" and see my subscription info. But if I attempt to use

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-AzureADGroup
Remove-AzureADGroup : The term 'Remove-AzureADGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureADGroup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-AzureADGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-MsolGroup
Get-MsolGroup : The term 'Get-MsolGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MsolGroup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-MsolGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Nothing is working, and every single guide I come across seems outdated by two years and refers to V2 or below for Azure PS connections.

My end goal it to delete a group from AD via cmdlet and I just cannot seem to get any of this to work.

Comment: Might be worth running `get-command -Module AzureRM` after Importing the module to get a list of commands that are available.

Comment: I'm not convinced `Install-Module AzureRM` is working as well as you think, might be worth running `Install-Module AzureRM -Verbose` and sharing the output.

Answer (score 1):

I......feel....really silly.
So after I posted this, I came across another technet link buried in another technet blog.

Turns out I don't need ANY of the above (for what I am trying to accomplish)
Simply followed this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/xplat-cli-install#option-2-use-an-installer

Then used these:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/azure-cli-arm-commands#azure-account-manage-your-account-information

Comment: Great that you solved it but... that doesn't belong in your question (or title). I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced article is really, really, really old, and you are now redirected to the new page if you attempt to go there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.1.0 .  You should only need to run
    Install-Module AzureRM

Also, the AzureAD module isnot part of AzureRM.  There are a small set of AD cmdlets included in AzureRM that allow you to manipulate AAD users, groups, and applications, but it does not have the full AD and MS Graph support of the AzureAD mdoule